# Can I limit the frequency of tab switches?

Tags: browser-addons, browser-tabs, ergonomics

I am looking to reduce the number of context switches I make in order to reduce mental strain I put on myself.
I notice that I sometimes switch between different browser tabs very frequently within a short span of time and that this is draining my energy.

Is there some plugin out there to limit the number of browser tab switches I can perform per minute?

Comment: At the limit, there are browsers that don’t support tabs at all and so you can never switch tabs. Would that be any use to you?

Comment: I think that would actually make the problem worse: you'd run out of tab switches and get stuck on a single tab until the counter resets.

Comment: @gronostaj that's exactly what I would need. To be forced to look out of my window for a minute or so.